# understanding proof of hensel's lemma

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> > **Hensel's Lemma**
> >
> > If $f(X)\in \mathbb{Z}_p [X]$ and $r \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ satisfies 
> >     $$f(r) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}, \quad f^\prime(r) \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p} $$
> >     Then there exists $r_n \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ such that
> >     $$f(r_n) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^n} \quad r_n \equiv r \pmod{p}$$

I want to prove this by induction. When $n=1$, it is trivial. If the inductive hypothesis holds for $n$, we seek $r_{n+1}$ such that
\begin{align}
f(r_{n+1}) &\equiv 0 \pmod{p^{n+1}}\\
r_{n+1} &\equiv r \pmod{p}
\end{align}
Since $f(r_{n+1}) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{n+1}} \Rightarrow f(r_{n+1}) \equiv 0\pmod{p^n}$, any root of $f(X) \pmod{p^{n+1}}$ reduces to a root of $f(X) \pmod{p^n}$. By the inductive hypothesis there is a root $r_n \pmod{p^n}$. I understand the above, but my textbook says that $r_{n+1} \equiv r_n \pmod{p^n}$. I don't understand why $r_{n+1}$ has to be congruent to $r_n$ modulo $p^n$. How can we verify this?

Comment: The proof seeks a suitable $r_{n+1}$ with the property that $r_{n+1}\equiv r_n\pmod{p^n}$ and **finds it**. So the proof works. As each $r_n$ is uniquely determined modulo $p^n$ in retrospect one sees the condition was necessary.

Comment: In your statement of Hensel's lemma I think $f(x)$ should be an element of $\mathbb Z[X]$, and the last two equalities should be mod $p^n$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown I don't understand it. Why $r_{n+1} \equiv r_n \pmod{p^n}$? please explain this to me more

Comment: @stewbasic Yes, $f\in\Bbb Z[X]$ but the very last congruence is definitely modulo $p$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown oops you are right.

Comment: @cokecokecoke it is not necessarily true that $r_{n+1}\equiv r_n\pmod{p^n}$. However we are proving existence, so we only need to find an example - we make a guess (AKA an ansatz) and verify it works. The fact that $f(r_{n+1})\equiv0\pmod{p^n}$ suggests that $r_{n+1}=r_n+ap^n$ is a good guess, but this doesn't need to be rigorous, as long as we rigorously prove that the guess works.

Comment: @stewbasic okay. I got it. thanks